# How can I use rosunit to unit test ROS nodes?

Tags: rostest, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the package `rosunit` [(wiki.ros.org](http://wiki.ros.org/rosunit) / [GitHub)](https://github.com/ros/ros/tree/lunar-devel/tools/rosunit) which seems to target unit testing of single ROS nodes (in comparison to [rostest](http://wiki.ros.org/rostest) which targets integration testing of ROS nodes). The last change of the wiki page is from 2014-06-08. Is the information still valid?

Otherwise:

- How can I use `rosunit`?
- How can I integrate it with `rosbuild`?
- What's the roadmap of `rosunit`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272572/how-can-i-use-rosunit-to-unit-test-ros-nodes?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2017-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Command line usage: http://wiki.ros.org/rosunit#Usage

**Python**

- Integration of unit test execution
  into cmake build:
  http://wiki.ros.org/unittest#Running_tests_as_part_of_.27make_test.27.2BAC8-CMakeLists.txt
- Invocation in main unit test file (no
  unittest test suite used):
  http://wiki.ros.org/unittest#unittest_code-1
- Invocation in main unit test file (unittest test suite used): http://wiki.ros.org/unittest#Using_Test_Suites

**C++**

- Integration of unit test execution into cmake build (package.xml, CMakeLists.txt): http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/gtest_configuration.html

---

Originally posted by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) with karma: 468 on 2017-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0